# Unknown ticking sound on bad ite power supply

Tags: power-supply

I have a power supply with the model number NU70-1120520-l1. It is supposed to have an output of 12vdc@5.2A. When i test the voltage i get a reading of 1-2vdc so i opened it and i hear a ticking with the frequency of about 2×/second. After removing the heat sinks and testing the voltage again i got a proper reading. So whatever the problem is its intermittent. But as far as i can see there is no relay or anything else i can see that would make such a noise. When i unplug the supply the noise decreases in frequency and then stops. What could cause such a noise in this video. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrl4aqnctn70doh/20171029_222750.mp4?dl=0 [image][image: surface mount ic on bottom]It would be much easier to replace the power supply but i am interested in the knowledge i will gain from diagnosing the problem with the circuit.  I can identify certain parts of the circuit and have a basic understanding of most electrical components.

Comment: the ticking sound could be caused by an electrical arc.  there may be a spark gap component that is used as overvoltage protection in the HV section.

Comment: Sound like your average partially shorted output and primary DC/DC IC is auto-restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a warning: **Power supplies like this one contain high-voltage capacitors that will hold a potentially deadly charge even after you unplugged it from the mains.** So if you unplug the power supply and then start to work on it, you might still get a pretty dangerous electric shock.

The problem with this power supply is most likely caused due to the controller chip's feedback/bootstrap circuitry not working.

Most power supplies have a controller chip (and switching transistors) on the primary side which creates the waveforms needed to drive the main ferrite transformer. This chip needs to be powered as well, so most manufacturers of such power supplies put an additional low-voltage winding on the transformer which will power the controller chip. This creates a chicken-and-egg problem, however: The controller chip can't start before it has power, but it doesn't get power before it starts and drives the transformer. In order to solve this problem, there's a large-value resistor that slowly charges a low-voltage capacitor from the ~300V line voltage. When this capacitor has enough voltage, the controller IC can start the power supply using the energy in the capacitor and then sustain its own operation using the auxiliary transformer winding.

If the auxiliary winding does not work for some reason, the chip will use up the capacitor's energy and then shut down again which results in a clicking noise from the transformer. This repeats every time the capacitor has reached the start-up voltage of the controller chip, causing rhytmic clicking.

If I had to take a guess, I'd say there's a dry solder joint or a dead diode somewhere in the thing.

Comment: I will search for shorts. I think thats more likely than a bad diode considering the problem is not happening after i opened it up. One other thing i noticed is when i do a short circuit current test it reads around 70mA for a second then zero. I would expect far more current draw before it would shut itself off.  Could the capacitor be bad?

Comment: @KeithBybee This is even more indicative of the power supply failing to start up due to a failure in the bootstrap circuitry. It tries to start, but then gives up because it can't power its controller IC or something similar. The high-power stuff within the power supply is probably fine because if it wasn't, you wouldn't get any voltage or current at all and the fuse would likely blow. The big capacitor probably isn't bad either. If it went away after opening the device, I'd say there's a bad solder joint somewhere.